# How to get whether OS is 32 bit or 64 bit by UNIX command?

Tags: unix, operating-system, command, bit

How will you get to know the bits of operating system? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean: how do you tell if it's e.g. a 32 bit OS or a 64 bit OS ?

Comment: if you want to know in c# thn i can help you

Comment: this might help you   [http://msgboard.alphasoftware.com/alphaforum/archive/index.php?t-97885.html](http://msgboard.alphasoftware.com/alphaforum/archive/index.php?t-97885.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In linux, the answer to such a generic question is just using

```
uname -m
```

or even:

```
getconf LONG_BIT
```

In C you can use the uname(2) system call.

In windows you can use:

```
systeminfo | find /I "System type"
```

or even examine the environment:

```
set | find "ProgramFiles(x86)"
```

(or with getenv() in C)

Answer (score 0):

Original question:

> ### How to know the bits of operating system in C or by some other way?

The correct way is to use some system API or command to get the architecture.
Comparing `sizeof` in C won't give you the system pointer size but the **target architecture's pointer size**. That's because most architectures/OSes are backward compatible so they can run previous 16 or 32-bit programs without problem. A 32-bit program's pointer is still 32-bit long even on 64 bit OS. And even on 64-bit architectures, some OSes may still use 32-bit pointers such as [x32-abi](https://sites.google.com/site/x32abi/)

Answer (score -1):

if you use c, you can get sizeof(void*) or sizeof(long) .if =8 then 64bits else 32bits.It's the same to all arch.

Comment: I am using Dev c++ compiler in which sizeof(void*) and sizeof(long) both are 4 instead of my OS is 64 bits??

Comment: @user1437033 sizeof() returns the size in bytes, so 4*8 = 32

Comment: @vonnyfly But my os is 64 bits??

Comment: -1: this really doesn't tell you anything - e.g. on x86-64 Linux you can build 32 bit or 64 bits executables (`gcc -m32 ...` or `gcc -m64 ...`) which will have 32 bit or 64 bit pointers regardless of the *64-bitness* of the OS.

Answer (score -1):

I'm so sorry for my carelessness and mistake.It's only for linux. In Linux Device Driver 3rd,11.1 section: Use of Standard C Types. It says

> The program can be used to show that long integers and pointers
>   feature a different size on 64-bit platforms, as demonstrated by
>   running the program on different Linux computers:
>
> arch   Size:  char  short  int  long   ptr long-long  u8 u16 u32 u64
>
> i386            1     2     4     4     4     8        1   2   4   8
>
> alpha           1     2     4     8     8     8        1   2   4   8
>
> armv4l          1     2     4     4     4     8        1   2   4   8
>
> ia64            1     2     4     8     8     8        1   2   4   8
>
> m68k            1     2     4     4     4     8        1   2   4   8
>
> mips            1     2     4     4     4     8        1   2   4   8
>
> ppc             1     2     4     4     4     8        1   2   4   8
>
> sparc           1     2     4     4     4     8        1   2   4   8
>
> sparc64         1     2     4     4     4     8        1   2   4   8
>
> x86_64          1     2     4     8     8     8        1   2   4   8

And there is some exception.For example:

> It's interesting to note that the SPARC 64 architecture runs with a
>   32-bit user space, so pointers are 32 bits wide there, even though
>   they are 64 bits wide in kernel space. This can be verified by loading
>   the kdatasize module (available in the directory misc-modules within
>   the sample files). The module reports size information at load time
>   using printk and returns an error (so there's no need to unload it):

@user1437033  I guess Windows isn't compatible with gcc standard .So you maybe get answer from windows' programmers. 
@Paul R  We should consider it regular code ,right? If you use cross compile tools ,such as arm(it only has 32bits),then you also can't get answer.

Ps:I don't support you use Dev c++ compiler,it's weird in many scenes and isn't standard.Code blocks or vs 2010 may be a good choice.
I hope this can help you.

Comment: there's nothing called "gcc standard" and this isn't a correct way to get the system's bitness either